# Building a Web Based Scheduling Database

Tags: database-design, web

I am looking to build a database that will help with counting up a number of physical objects on a day-to-day basis for a number of years (rental cars, for example), and I'm hoping to get some input from some of the smart people here as to the best way to go about this.

Currrently we keep track of all of our cars in a rather complicated excel sheet, incrementing or decrementing the total count on a given day as needed. For example, 2 Toyota Camrys may go from the "available" state to the "maintenance" state on July 21st, and return back to being available on the 30th.

The problem with this method is that it becomes quite cumbersome to manage multiple, overlapping changes, as well as to look far into the future or into the past (for example, adding compatibility for cars we expect to receive in 2016 makes the Excel sheet too big).

I'm thinking that there must be some sort of database framework that allows for easy counting of objects (day by day, preferably) as I have described. Ideally, data input into the database could be performed from a data entry form on a webpage.

Are there any database frameworks that have this sort of scheduling function? What sort of scripting languages might be useful to build something like this? I have no clue where to even start here, so thanks in advance.

-P

Comment: All databases do this, but there are bigger questions here. If this is for work, you will need to provision a server, buy a license, create the DB tables. Then build a web site with HTML and back end code, get it hosted internally, write the T-SQL to communicate it, manage access rights etc. Have you asked your IT department to do this?

Comment: I have not, I was just curious as to whether something like this was possible, which it seems to be. I'll have to ask around regarding your questions.

Are there any free database packages or HTML5 plugins that might make this job a bit easier? I don't have any functional experience with database programming, but perhaps you could point me in the right direction.